# Getting a win32 window and adding menu programmatically

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a dll that provides cross-platform app UI. For windows the underlying platform uses Win 32 API. I am trying to create a Win UI 3 app wrapping this dll and adding additional functionality. Specifically, after I make the call to DLL which launches a window, I want to be able to get hold of that window (the dll call doesn't return anything, just launches the window) and programmatically add menu to it. Is it possible to do this? Looking for a C# solution.

Comment: I don't believe that WinUI 3 is compatible with classic USER32 menus.

Comment: Whether you want to [build a C# .NET app with WinUI 3 and Win32 interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/desktop-winui3-app-with-basic-interop)? If so, you could try to use `WindowNative.GetWindowHandle` to retrieve the window handle (HWND) for a WinUI 3 Window object.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT, that example you provided has the window created in c# and then using the GetWIndowHandle API to get the Win32 window handle. My case is different. The DLL call creates a Win32 window and launches it. I tried the FindWIndowW mentioned below but for some reason it didn't work. Then I had to use the EnumWIndows (after about 10ms sleep delay) and then got hold of the window. Currently in the process of decorating the window with menus.

Comment: This doesn't sound like the normal way to write a program. Why are you hacking away at windows that don't belong to you?

Comment: That's a good question @DavidHeffernan. The dll code actually belongs to me. But it is based on a cross-platform UI library that I don't have control on. I already have an app built for Mac and now trying to create one for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to stackoverflow and Copilot, I managed to solve this. Here is an outline of the solution.

1. Getting the window

```cs
                Thread.Sleep(10); // Without sleep, EnumWindows didn't return the window
                IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowEx(className, null);
                if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) { // for some reason FindWindowEx didn't work so as a fallback I used EnumWindows
                    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
                } else
                {
                    AppMenu.SetupMenu(hWnd);
                }
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

        delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        static bool EnumWindowsCallback(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            uint processId;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);
            if (processId != currentProcessId) // I already have current process id using Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            {
                return true;
            }
            string windowTitle = GetWindowTitle(hWnd);
            if (windowTitle == appName)
            {
                AppMenu.SetupMenu(hWnd);
            }
            return true;
        }

        static string GetWindowTitle(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, nChars);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
```

2. To setup menu on the window, my AppMenu class has

```cs
public static void SetupMenu(IntPtr hWnd)
{
            IntPtr hMenu = CreateMenu();

            IntPtr fMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(fMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_OPEN_GIF, "&Open GIF File\tCtrl+N");
            AppendMenu(fMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_OPEN_GIF_URL, "&Open GIF URL\tCtrl+Shift+N");
            // more menu items
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (uint)fMenu, "File");
            // more menus
}
```

3. Register for menu item selection (some of the constants below are from winuser.h that I picked up on the net (don't know how to make use of them from standard libraries instead of defining them in the app)

```cs
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

            var result = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, EVENT_OBJECT_INVOKED, IntPtr.Zero, WinEventProc, (uint)App.currentProcessId, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD);
            if (result == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error setting up win event hook");
            }
```

4. Lastly (this was the missing piece for me for a couple of hours), SetWinEventHook will only work if there is a message loop.

```cs
            MSG msg;
            while (GetMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage(ref msg);
                DispatchMessage(ref msg);
                if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                    break;
            }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MSG
        {
            public IntPtr hwnd;
            public uint message;
            public IntPtr wParam;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public uint time;
            public POINT pt;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }
```

Comment: Github Copilot sucks. Quality code would obviously use `Thread.Sleep(1337);`.

Comment: @Siva I'm glad you have got your solution and thank for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
…
// Import winapi function from dll
[DllImport(User32.dll)]
static extern Uint32 FindWindowW(String className, String windowName);
// Use it
Uint32 window=FindWindowW(className, windowName);
// Some code painting on window…`
```

That uses P/Invoke to Import a win32api function called FindWindowW. You've already Create the window in that dll using winapi, so you may know its name or class name, then you can use FindWindowW to find it. That function returns a handle to the window, you then can use it in your application.
For more information, refer to:
[Calling win32 functions from dlls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2003/july/net-column-calling-win32-dlls-in-csharp-with-p-invoke),
and [FindWindowW](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww).
I'm not very familiar to C#, hope it'll help.

Comment: `FindWindow` (which you should have declared without the `W` and specify Charset=Auto instead in the attribute) returns an IntPtr, not a Uint32.

Comment: For some reason the FindWindow didn't work for me. I used EnumWindows (after a small pause with Time.Sleep) and then get hold of the window. I also managed to programmatically add menu and menu items. But I am now stuck in writing event handlers for them. Seems there is WndProc callback but that is setup by the dll that opens the window and I have no way of overwriting it. I was looking into setting up window event handler but couldn't get it to work yet.